# ember-resources trackedTask with cached value

Tags: ember.js

I've recently started looking into the nice `ember-resources` library because I came to the point my data fetching routine required some reactivity. Since we tend to use the `ember-concurrency` tasks in our project I wanted to follow the common pattern and I was happy to realise that `ember-resources` support `ember-concurrency` tasks out of the box.

Now i've got a dependant tracked property which is basically a timer and it's being updated every minute. What I want to do is to be able to run my task say every two minutes. The question is how to achieve this?

Here goes my pseudo-code:

```
  // that's my component
  @restartableTask
  *fetchFeed() {
    yield timeout(1);
    return yield this.store.queryRecord('item', {...});
  }

  get currentTime() {
    // this one returns a tracked variable which is updated every minute
  }

  feedResource = trackedTask(this, this.fetchFeed, () => [this.currentTime]);

  // this is the corresponding hbs
  {{#if this.feedResource.isRunning}}
    <LoadingSpinner />
  {{else}}
    {{this.feedResource.value}}
  {{/if}}
```

what I want to do is basically

```
get every2Minutes() {
  return Math.trunc(this.currentTime.second() / 2)
}

feedResource = trackedTask(this, this.fetchFeed, () => [this.every2Minutes]);
```

but it's still run on every minute. I've tried using the `@cached` attribute and a custom cache solution but it didn't help - despite that the cache gave me the correct value, i.e. only even ones, the task was still fired every minute. Can I tell the `trackedTask` to not fire if the dependency wasn't changed?

Answer (score 2):

Hi, I'm the author of ember-resources! glad you're having fun with the library!

> this one returns a tracked variable which is updated every minute

While this is clever, if the variable isn't used in the task, it "feels weird". I don't have better words for this.

But, to directly answer your question, I'd define `currentTime` like this:

```
const ClockEveryOtherMinute = resource(({ on }) => {
  let time = cell(new Date());
  let interval = setInterval(
    () => time.current = new Date(), 
    2 * 60 * 1000, // 2 minutes
  );

  on.cleanup(() => clearInterval(interval));

  return () => time.current;
});
class Foo {
  // `@use` is required when a resource returns a single value
  @use currentTime = ClockEveryOtherMinute;

  feedResource = trackedTask(this, this.fetchFeed, () => [this.currentTime]);

  // ...etc
}
```

Here is an [interactive demo of something very similar](https://limber.glimdown.com/edit?format=glimdown&t=%23%20Clock%20as%20a%20Resource%0A%0AUsing%20%60setInterval%60%20%2B%20%60clearInterval%60%0A%0A%60%60%60gjs%20live%0Aimport%20Component%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Fcomponent%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20cell%2C%20resource%20%7D%20from%20%27ember-resources%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20Clock%20%3D%20resource((%7B%20on%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20time%20%3D%20cell(new%20Date())%3B%0A%20%20let%20interval%20%3D%20setInterval(()%20%3D%3E%20time.current%20%3D%20new%20Date()%2C%201000)%3B%0A%0A%20%20on.cleanup(()%20%3D%3E%20clearInterval(interval))%3B%0A%0A%20%20let%20formatter%20%3D%20new%20Intl.DateTimeFormat(%27en-US%27%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20hour%3A%20%27numeric%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20minute%3A%20%27numeric%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20second%3A%20%27numeric%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20hour12%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20return%20()%20%3D%3E%20formatter.format(time.current)%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0A%3Ctemplate%3E%0A%20%20It%20is%3A%20%3Ctime%3E%7B%7BClock%7D%7D%3C%2Ftime%3E%0A%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%60%60%60%0A)

However, I think there may be a more ergonomic way --

In a scenario where you want recurring behavior, there are a couple approaches you could take:

- invoke the task once and use a while loop to do something periodically
- use a constructor/destructor combo with setInterval

These are somewhat separate from the `trackedTask` helper utility, as the `trackedTask` helper utility "only" does lazy invocation of the `.perform` method on a task when a property on the `TaskInstance` would be accessed. So... I'm not actually sure if your getter's return would be updated if the task is re-performed every couple minutes manually. I'm maybe.. 60% sure it would? (this is something I don't have tests for).

Anywho back to the options:

#### invoke the task once

```
class Foo extends Component {
  @tracked items;

  @task
  *fetchFeed() {
    yield timeout(1);

    while(true) {
      this.items = yield this.store.queryRecord('item', {...});
      yield timeout(1000 * 60 * 2); // 2 minutes
    }
  }

  get hasItems() {
    return Boolean(this.items?.length);
  }
}
```

```
  // this is the corresponding hbs
  {{#if this.hasItems}}
    {{this.items}}
  {{else}}
    <LoadingSpinner />
  {{/if}}
```

#### using setInterval

```
import { registerDestructor } from '@ember/destroyable';

class Foo extends Component {
  @tracked items;

  constructor(owner, args) {
    super(owner, args);

    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (isDestroyed(this) || isDestroying(this)) return;
    
      this.fetchFeed.perform();
    }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
    registerDestructor(this, () => {
      clearTimeout(interval);
    });

    // initial perform
    this.fetchFeed.perform();
  }

  @task
  *fetchFeed() {
    yield timeout(1);

    return yield this.store.queryRecord('item', {...});
  }

  get hasItems() {
    return Boolean(this.fetchFeed.lastSuccessful?.value?.length);
  }
}
```

```
  // this is the corresponding hbs
  {{#if this.hasItems}}
    {{this.fetchFeed.lastSuccessful.value}}
  {{else}}
    <LoadingSpinner />
  {{/if}}
```

#### A "do something every 2 minutes API"

I'm ‍♂️ on this approach, but for completeness, it's probably reasonable to know that it's possible (I'm going to hand-wave over the implementation, as that could be other stack-overflow questions):

```
const doEveryTwoMinutes = resourceFactory((callback) => {
  // ...
  return resource(({ on }) => {
    // ...
  });
});

class Foo extends Component {
  @use feed = doEveryTwoMinutes(() => {
    return this.fetchFeed.perform(); // returns a task
  });

  @task
  *fetchFeed() {
    yield timeout(1);

    return yield this.store.queryRecord('item', {...});
  }

  get hasItems() {
    return Boolean(this.feed.length);
  }
}
```

```
  // this is the corresponding hbs
  {{#if this.hasItems}}
    {{this.feed}}
  {{else}}
    <LoadingSpinner />
  {{/if}}
```

(no `trackedTask` needed, we rely on the internal tracked-state of a `TaskInstance`)

---

Why do these approaches not need `trackedTask`?
because we have "events" that we know about that cause the task to be performed -- and ember-concurrency is really good at being "an event handler", of sorts -- whereas ember-resources is more about deriving data (maybe eventually), with cleanup.

Comment: Hi @NullVoxPopuli. I knew that you're the author so I was hoping you'll be able to help. I just quickly read through this and perhaps I didn't clearly explained my problem. The timer which is updated every minute is our "global" resource which is available as a service (probably bad design too but that's how it currently is). What I wanted to do was basically to reuse that existing timer thing to run the fetch depending on it (I don't need to run it every minute or even 2 minutes but to implement a bit more sophisticated logic depending on the time).

Comment: But after some pondering I guess I'll be able to implement a local timer resource like you suggested. A quick question though: how can one trigger a resource manually? I.e. is there any way I could attach the `feedResource` to a button click?

Comment: re your first question -- sorry I misunderstood -- here is an example util that may help with those endeavors:  https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-resources/blob/main/ember-resources/src/util/debounce.ts#L60

-- 
for the second,
resources don't have a concept of triggered as they're are "all in" on derived data -- but they could provide a method that can do the triggering (if you build that in)